# xml configure for index search in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

Please give me an example to index database use hibernate 3, lucense search and xml confiure.

Currently i can't find equivalent xml configure tags for annotation: @DocumentId.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to use xml as a replacement for Lucene annotations in Hibernate Search, as there is with some of the other Hibernate search annotations.

You'll either have to use annotations, or create the functionality for mapping xml to annotations yourself.

It doesn't look like it would be too horrible to modify or extend [org.hibernate.reflection.java.EJB3OverridenAnnotationReader](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/jboss.jboss-embeddable-ejb3/hibernate-all/1.0.0.Alpha9/org/hibernate/reflection/java/EJB3OverridenAnnotationReader.java), if it's really necessary.

Found a few notes with some guidelines on the right way to go about this:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToImplementXMLMappingForHibernateSearch